# Django admin queryset limited to 100 items

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-queryset, django-database

Here's the situation:

I have a model called Profile. There are currently more than 200 Profile items in my DB.
I have another model called Item.
These two models have a one-to-one relationship.

In the Profile list page I can see all Profile items I have in the DB. Good.
In the Item edit page I have a dropdown field (called "profile") that should list all the Profile items in my DB (more than 200).
The problem is that it only lists the first 100 items. Also, the same field displays "---------" when the related Profile item is above the 100th in the DB.

It's like there's some setting that limit the queryset to 100 in the Django admin.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you set `limit_choices_to` on the `OneToOneField`?

Comment: @JamesBennett Nope, should I?

Comment: Can you post the models and their corresponding `ModelAdmin`s?